# c++ finding the first missing positive value in an unsorted array

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm trying to understand [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/first-missing-positive/discuss/17179/easy-to-understand-c++-solution) solution that finds the first missing positive value in an unsorted array. It works like this

> 1, locate min and max of the input, and mark the negative values with a
>   special positive value.
>       2. After ensure the min starts with 1 (otherwise we know ‘1’ is missing), we scan the input, similar to counting sort, since we can’t
>   use extra space. I can’t mark the values to negative to indicate the
>   slot is taken.
>
> 3.scan the range the input where we just did count on between valMin and valMax, if we can any slot isn’t taken (as in is positive) then we
>   know that’s the slot where the missing number is.

My question is what are these 2 lines doing?

```
int &val = nums[abs(num) - valMin];
if (val > 0) val = -val;
```

For example if your input array is `{ 1, -3, 2, 1, 4, 3 };` 
after this point your array becomes `-1,-2147483647,-2,-1,4,3`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <limits.h>

using namespace std;

int firstMissingPositive(vector<int> &A) {

        int valMin = INT32_MAX, valMax = 0;

        for (auto &num:A) {

            if (num > 0) {
                valMin = min(valMin, num);
                valMax = max(valMax, num);

            } else {

                num = INT32_MAX;

            }
        }

        for (auto &num:A)
            cout << num << ",";

        cout << "\n";

        if (valMin != 1) return 1;
        for (int &num:A) {
            if (num != 0 and abs(num) != INT32_MAX) {
                int &val = A[abs(num) - valMin];
                if (val > 0) val = -val;
            }
        }
        for (auto &num:A)
                    cout << num << ",";

        //scan the range the input where we just did count on between valMin and valMax,
        //if we can any slot isn’t taken (as in is positive) then we know that’s the slot where the missing number is.

        for (int i = valMin; i < valMax; ++i) {
            if (A[i - valMin] > 0) return i;
        }
        return valMax + 1;
    }

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, -3, 2, 1, 4, 3 };
    int answer = firstMissingPositive(v);
    cout << answer;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's also a completely garbage loop; since if you pass it the vector `[1, 100, 200, 300]` you'll find it just crashes.  (You'll notice that it's trying to edit the item in the array of index <value of array item> - and thus by having these large numbers it's going to try to edit data out of bounds)  It should ensure that the value is in range of the size of vector as well as being != 0 or +/- INT32_MAX

Comment: @UKMonkey `[1, 100, 200, 300]` seems to work ok?

Comment: try replacing it with `.at()` rather than `[]` and you'll see the exception get thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Here,

> since we can’t use extra space. I ***can** mark the values to negative to indicate the slot is taken.

The solution is using the same *input array* to mark the slots which are taken.

These lines :

`int &val = nums[abs(num) - valMin];
 if (val > 0) val = -val;`

*abs(num)*, because there could be a case like {0,-4,-5,6,1,2,3}, so '2' will be marked '-2' before it is iterated.

These lines are,

1. Getting value at the index 'num' - 1, essentially, as valMin will be 1 always, otherwise it would have returned the function.
2. Then checking if this value is positive, that means this index has never been checked before by the logic, else it would be negative. So, if the value is positive, make is negative, to mark that **value corresponding to this index is present in the array**.

So, for example, in the input array, the iterations will be like :

> {0,-4,-5,6,1,2,3} => {0,MAX,MAX,6,1,2,3}
> {0,MAX,MAX,**6**,1,2,3} => {0,MAX,MAX,6,1,-2,3}
> {0,MAX,MAX,6,**1**,2,3} => {0,MAX,MAX,6,1,-2,3}
> {0,MAX,MAX,6,1,**2**,3} => {0,-MAX,MAX,6,1,-2,3}
> {0,MAX,MAX,6,1,2,**3**} => {0,-MAX,-MAX,6,1,-2,3}

Then, `if (A[i - valMin] > 0) return i;` will check the first entry which is positive, that is `i-valMin` or should I say `i-1`. So, essentially, the first positive `index + 1` is the answer.

Here, in the example input array, `{0,-MAX,-MAX,6,1,-2,3}`; the first positive index is 3, so the answer is 3+1 i.e. 4

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to code information about presence of number `n` as a sign of a number in position `A[n-valMin]`.

```
-1,-2147483647,-2,-1,4,3
```

Here we see that 1, 2, 3, 4 are present, because first 4 array elements have minus sign. So, the first absent positive number is 5.